# The @ClassRule 'resources' must be static Kotlin

Tags: junit

I am getting this error:

```
org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @ClassRule 'resources' must be static.
```

When setting up my Dropwizard Kotlin application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable that it is complaining about must be annotated with `@JvmField` and inside of a companion object. So, for example:

```
companion object {
    @ClassRule
    @JvmField
    val resources = ...
}
```